# Connection to remote MySQL Database fails

Tags: database, magento-1, cpanel

We copied our domain, database and filesystem to another server @ rackspeed.
I opened the cPanel and added the ip address of the old server in "Remote-MySQL" so that the old server can connect to the new database. Then I created a second user and added him to the rackspeed database.

Then I connected to the old server and entered the database credentials of the rackspeed server with the new user. But now I get to see the offline site, so the remote connection is not working?

Am I missing something?

Comment: So you have edited your env file to point to your previous database? so the host name has been set to point to an IP Address or URL and the credentials are the same. also make sure you dont have a firewall on that server if you do then you may need to whitelist the IP address and remote ports